# Powershell Select-String to include a wildcard

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to use Select-String to find something is a known string of characters, followed by either a `/` or `$` followed by another known string of characters.

So suppose literal string 1 is `X` and literal string 2 is `Y`, how do I look for the string `X/Y` or `X$Y` in powershell?

Comment: This should work, try  `X[/$]Y`

Comment: https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\users\js> Echo a/b | Select-String a.b

a/b


PS C:\users\js> Echo 'a$b' | Select-String a.b

a$b
```

Comment: Right, so how would I do a single statement that returns either of those? (Or let's say any character in between 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: Edited it for any single character.

Answer (score 0):

I'd compound the RegEx even if strings are simple here:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\28\SO_56349782.ps1

$String1 = [regex]::Escape("X")
$String2 = [regex]::Escape("Y")
$RegEx   = [regex]"$String1(\/|\$)$String2"

$Text = @'
foo X/Y 
foo X$Y baz
foo X/Y bar X$Y baz
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$Text | Select-String -Pattern $RegEx -AllMatches

($Text | Select-String -Pattern $RegEx -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Sample output:

```
foo X/Y
foo X$Y baz
foo X/Y bar X$Y baz
```

---

```
X/Y
X$Y
X/Y
X$Y
```

Comment: That's really helpful. So the (\/|\$) is what I didn't know. I'm guessing \ indicates that the following character is literal? So it's basically just saying look for '/' or '$' there?

Comment: Exactly, it's called an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` = OR. To separate it from the rest it's enclosed in a capture group `()`To match characters literal with a special meaning in a regex they have to be escaped with a backslash.